# how to remove time from datetime string with robot framework

Tags: robotframework

below is my code to get a string

```
${get_deviceinstalldate}    get text    ${x_properties_deviceinstalldate}
log to console    Device Install Date:${get_deviceinstalldate}
```

=========
result is: Device Install Date:09/06/2023 13:14

question is how can I remove 13:14 from the string above i just want the date as 09/06/2023 ? thank you

I tried

```
${get_deviceinstalldate_default}=    remove string    ${get_deviceinstalldate}    ${space}    :
```

but its result is: Device Install Date:09/06/20231314
how can i removed the last 4 numbers 1314 ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at I example I assume that datetime string is fixes length. In this case you could extract fixed length substring from your string:

```
${date}    Set Variable    ${get_deviceinstalldate[:10]}
```

Other approach is to split string on space and take left side. To so you need `Split String` keyword from `String` library:

```
${date}    @{rest}    Split String    ${get_deviceinstalldate}    ${SPACE}
```